# Multiple WCF named pipe clients connecting without repeatedly invoking the endpoint's constructor?

Tags: wcf, named-pipes, duplex

I've got a WCF server/client setup using named pipes, and my client connects to the host process (already running) as follows:

```
var pipeFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IArbiter>(this, new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress(new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/IArbiter")));
arbiter = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
```

This is fine for the first client connecting, but when the second client connects, a new instance of the IArbiter implementation is created (the arbiter's constructor is called every time a connection happens).

Is there a way to find the "existing" instance of that arbiter at the endpoint address?

Comment: That is the default behavior of WCF - each request gets its own instance of the service class. And I personally would leave it that way - it's the easiest and most scalable way of running your WCF service. Why is that a problem for you?

Comment: Because the arbiter class is intended to channel multiple WCF clients into one tcp/ip message interface.  I suppose I can just implement it as a singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, just need to set this above my class implementation:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```